# Best Method For Clearing User Data On Shared Windows Device?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, scheduled-task, batch-file

I have had a client request that I setup a user account on a Windows device that will clear all user profile data once the account has been logged off. The computer is a shared device that will be used by guests and there cannot be any reference to the previous guests data.

My question is, what is the best method for achieving this? Is there a way I can achieve this with Group Policy, or some form of Roaming Profile that's automatically deleted? Or am I better off clearing with a batch file and Task Scheduler that deletes Documents, App Data, etc.

I know that this is often setup in public libraries and internet cafes, I'm just not sure how.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Smithy

Comment: Looks like there is a group policy for this ```Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\USER PROFILES\Delete cached copies of roaming profiles``` you should configure it for the account that will be wiped, but I will suggest to use the guest user for this, because it is already set to be that kind of user.

Comment: You need to look into deep freeze or something similar; tasks and that group policy would not fit the bill for "cannot be any reference to the previous guests data"